# Setting REMOTE_USER for apache logs using php

Tags: php, apache

In mod_perl i can do something like:

```
$r->user("username");
```

And then the username will show up in the username section in the logs.

Is there a way to do this in php? without having to modify apache?

**Edit**: So far i've tried both:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] = "username";
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = "username";
apache_setenv('REMOTE_USER', "username")
```

with no luck

**Edit2:** 
Apache logs are in the format of:

ipAddress **REMOTE_USER** IDENT datetime... etc

I'm trying to set REMOTE_USER without using apache's mod_auth, but php code.

Comment: Have you done a `phpinfo()` as an authenticated user?  Somewhere in the resulting data, you should find your username...

Comment: my authenticated user is coming in programmaticly, not from apache. I know how to get the user from apache, i don't know how to tell apache what the user is.

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you or are you not trying to determine the username of the HTTP-authenticated user?  If the user isn't HTTP-authenticated, then the things you're trying to do won't work.  Can you edit your question to explain the nature of the authentication in more detail?

Comment: I'm trying to set it to save it to the apache logs.

All of the things i've listed thus far is setting, not getting.
Updated question.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a likely option: [apache_setenv()](http://php.net/apache_setenv)

Comment: Very cool, I did not know about that one, but unfortunately it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use apache_setenv() along with changing your log_format to include %{REMOTE_USER}e

So you're basically passing the remote user as an environment variable, and grabbing that value in the log_format. As far as I know there's no way to override the 'original' variable.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you could simply override/provide the variable by setting the required super-global as you would any other variable. However that being said, a quick peak at the PHP docs and the variable you speak of isn't listed:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: Sorry, see my update. I've already tried the two most obvious (to me) $_SERVER items.