# How to set REMOTE_USER

Tags: php, apache, session, localhost

I'm developing a PHP-based application that will be used in a sigle sign-on environment. I rely on the REMOTE_USER variable for user information. Is it possible set REMOTE_USER on my local machine (MAMP on Mac OS 10.6) using dummy values to make local development easier?

Comment: Retagged to add php which might help you get an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting REMOTE_USER for apache logs using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050589/setting-remote-user-for-apache-logs-using-php)

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in a config file or at the top of your file, write:

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1')
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] = 'whatever';
```